# Kubernetes dashboard spekt8 doesn't display any data

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to install a kubernetes dashboard  [spekt8](https://github.com/spekt8/spekt8)
I do everything according to the instructions on their page (and *kubectl apply -f fabric8-rbac.yaml*. too)
After installation, the dashboard page loads, but I don’t see any Kubernetis resources in the dashboard, although pods are running in Kubernetis itself and the namespace is also default.
Tell me which way to dig.

```
$ kubectl logs spekt8-6457b9d8d5-fr9jr

> docker-kubernetes-udemy3@1.0.0 server /usr/src/app
> nodemon src/server/server.js

[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node src/server/server.js`
Listening on port 3000....
```